# How to query records containing certain number?

Tags: mysql, sql

Edited: How to query records containing certain number, USING REGEXP?

Data base:

```
id | number
1 | ["5","8","9","19","1"]
2 | ["2","3","8","11","10"]
3 | ["1","14","3","22","15"]
4 | ["20","8","4","6","7"]
5 | ["3","9","14","20","10"]
```

In sql, how to query only the records that have the number 8, for example? (Id's 1, 2 and 4)

Comment: what data type is your number field?

Answer (score 2):

You don't tell us what data type number is, so I've assumed it to be text.

```
Select * from mytable
Where number like '%"8"%'
```